# For LVM on LUKS when does the partition ID for a new install get set to 8e?

Tags: arch-linux, gparted, lvm, luks

Trying to decipher my notes from the *last* time I installed LVM on Luks, I have a note to create three "primary" partitions for a Dual-Boot installation. The trouble is, after I install Windows, but before I install Linux--when I'm setting up the Luks/LVM Linux partition and get to the lvcreate step, I receive the error: `Incorrect metadata area header checksum on /dev/sdb3 at offset 4096`. (I keep Windows just for testing purposes and so its not encrypted)

From research I've learned this results from the partition id `83 Linux` that should be `8e LVM` instead. I've confirmed the same with `fsisk` output generated from my last successful installation.

I've *tried* to create an "extended" partition instead of a "primary" partition (in step 3), but this partition is unrecognized by the `pvcreate` step. I can't figure out when I made the `8e` change to the parition. My steps are as follows:

```
4) Create physical volume on Linux partition.    
   # pvcreate /dev/sda3    
5) Create volume group 
   # vgcreate cryptVG /dev/sda3 
6) Gain access to the unmounted root volume.    
   # lvm vgchange -a y 
7.1) Create the encrypted container for the LVM,    
   # cryptsetup -y -c aes-xts-plain -s 512 luksFormat /dev/sda3    
7.2) Open the crypt container for installation,
   # cryptsetup luksOpen    /dev/sda3 cryptVG
8) # pvcreate /dev/mapper/cryptVG
9) # vgcreate cryptVG /dev/mapper/cryptVG 
10) # lvcreate -n root -L 15.5G cryptVG
```

Step 9 is also giving me a problem. Error says cryptVG was already created, but doesn't the LVM volume need to be set up *inside* the encrypted steps? (It may have been a later edit to my list of steps when I installed Arch on top of the original Luks crypt I made for Fedora, or not). Help me edit my notes to make the *correct partition id* by explaining when the extended volume is created in the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're seeing is because you're encrypting the raw disk partition rather than the volume group (step 7).  So you're overwriting the LVM information with the crypto headers.

Your next question is going to be "Ok, so how do I do this?"  For that I'm going to suggest Google...  Conceptually there are a few ways it can be done, it just depends on what you're trying to protect / hide.

For example, you could create the lUKS container and protect everything on the partition, including the metadata.  Or, you encrypt each logical volume individually with different keys.  There are benefits and problems with each approach.

Comment: I've accidentally encrypted each LV before. Its definitely not the goal. Here, the rub is if I don't create the PV, then I can't create the VG. And if I don't create the VG, then I don't have something to open in step 7.2. The steps in this checklist worked before. I may have added 8 & 9 for non Luks (which is the mystery referred to in my post). Otherwise these steps by themselves plus whatever I did in Gparted in step 3, do the trick... So I guess I'm not clear what is your answer--what is the code you suggest to replace step 7?

Comment: @xtian: This will get you past encrypting the physical volume and overwriting the volume group:

Add 6.2: 
`lvcreate -n encryptedLV -L20G`

Change 7.1 to:
`cryptsetup -y -c aes-xts-plain -s 512 luksFormat /dev/cryptVG`/encryptedLV

Comment: Then to mount the filesystem automatically on boot, it will depend on the specific OS you're running.  You'll need to arrange for `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/cryptVG/encryptedLV encryptedData` to be run.  Then `mount /dev/mapper/encryptedData /somewhere/you/want` or something in /etc/fstab...